# metpy get_layer returns only the the first three values

Tags: python, python-3.x, metpy

All,
The MetPy get_layer function returns only the first 3 pressure values from the following pressure array (is that is correct?)

```
import numpy as np
from metpy.calc import get_layer
plev = np.array(( 1000.,950.,900.,850.,800.,750.,700.,650.,600., 
            550.,500.,450.,400.,350.,300.,250.,200., 
            175.,150.,125.,100., 80., 70., 60., 50., 
            40., 30., 25., 20.,10. ))*100 # Pascall

pre = plev*units.Pa

print(get_layer(pre))

[<Quantity([100000.  95000.  90000.], 'pascal')>]
```

I just found that when I use this function "mean_pressure_weighted(pre,tem)"
which seems, after comparison with "print(np.trapz(tem[:3]*pre[:3],x=pre[:3])/np.trapz(pre[:3],x=pre[:3]))", to use the first three values only.

tem is defined as

```
t   =np.array((29.3,28.1,23.5,20.9,18.4,15.9,13.1,10.1, 6.7, 3.1,   \
        -0.5,-4.5,-9.0,-14.8,-21.5,-29.7,-40.0,-52.4,   \
       -59.2,-66.5,-74.1,-78.5,-76.0,-71.6,-66.7,-61.3, \
       -56.3,-51.7,-50.7,-47.5 ))

tkel = t+273.15
tem = tkel*units.degK
```

I am not sure exactly how get_layer work, yet I think that mean_pressure_weight would not work probably with the current output of the get_layer.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_layer()` returns a layer out of an array, given the bottom and depth of the layer (optionally working with either pressures or heights). When depth is not passed in, it defaults to a depth of 100 hPa. When bottom is not specified, it defaults to the maximum pressure it was given.

So in your case, with those defaults, it's going to give the levels in the lowest 100 hPa, which would be 1000, 950, and 900, as shown in your example above.

Comment: In this case, this function may cause a problem with the mean_pressure_weighted function since defaults depth is being used that is not explicitly stated in the definition of the ```mean_pressure_weight``` [link] (https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.mean_pressure_weighted.html#metpy.calc.mean_pressure_weighted) This is what is stated "depth (pint.Quantity, optional) – Depth of the layer in meters or hPa.
" Nothing about the default value.

Comment: I described that above.

Comment: Will be clarified with https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/pull/2971

Comment: Not sure if it is a good idea to return a list of the pressure levels used in the calculations... users may get confused about how pressure/height levels are selected when calling ```mean_pressure_weight``` or ```weighted_continuous_average```.

Comment: That would be a significant API change that would need to be discussed on the MetPy issue tracker. It would also be a little odd to return a data reduction (the average) and then also return the level values that led to that reduction. A more interesting question is whether we should change to force a specification of depth.

Comment: Yes, using all pressure levels in the calculations by default would be better.

Comment: This is more about science. Did you encounter any problems/calculations that use the ```mean_pressure_weight``` function? I know that ```weighted_continous_average``` is vital for calculating too many things, but I did not recall that I found a specific problem that use the ```mean_pressure_Weight```  function.

Comment: At this point the `mean_pressure_weight` is part of MetPy's API, so changes/removal have to account of API breakage, etc. Regardless, this discussion is not well-suited, nor appropriate, for the the comment section of Stack Overflow. If you have additional concerns, I'd suggest starting a discussion on MetPy's GitHub Discussions page: https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/discussions